# Library ECB shows "Change New Button Order" for all users

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type, ecb-menu

We have a document library which has content type management enabled. The library allows two content types, one based on Document, the other on Document Set.

We also have a custom action attached to the ECB that starts a workflow to set specific permissions on the item. Our custom action respects user permissions properly and does not show to user who should not see it.

Our problem is that the ECB now shows "Change New Button Order" for Document Set items to all users, no matter what their permission level. This is *not* a custom action - it is added by SharePoint automatically when you enable content type management on a library which accepts folders - or document sets, which inherit from folders. Only users with Manage List permissions on this library should see the "Change New Button Order" action, but SharePoint is showing it to everyone.

[image: User with only Read permissions can modify this setting, breaking inheritance]

We don't want read-only users to be able to do this; we don't even want Contributor users to be able to do it.

How do I make it so that only Manage List permission levels can see this item in the ECB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have custom action for ECB then you can specify the `Rights` attribute to `ManageLists`

For e.g.

```
<CustomAction
 Id="Ribbon.Blah.ReplacementButton"
 Location="EditControlBlock"
 Rights ="ManageLists"
 RegistrationId="0x01AB"
 RegistrationType="ContentType">    
     //some other stuff
</CustomAction>
```

You can also try other permission level if you want: http://techwirenews.com/setting-rights-for-custom-actions-using-sharepoint-designer-2010-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/

Comment: It's not the custom action we're trying to hide - we already use a rights mask on that. What we want is for the "Change New Button Order" action that SharePoint automatically adds when you have a library that allows the folder content type (document set), to respect permissions and not show to people with only read access.

Comment: You can add Custom action to library with a specific content type, which will enable you to target your ECB customization based on content type. See my updated response.

Comment: Again, our custom action has nothing to do with "Change New Button Order" - SharePoint adds that automatically. Our custom action *is not showing*, which is fine. What we want to hide is NOT a custom action. So you're saying we need to add *another* custom action that OVERRIDES "Change New Button Order" that SharePoint adds by default, and explicitly mask the permissions on it?

Comment: As I understood it, you might want to apply permission to "Change New Button Order" based on specific Content Type. I still haven't understood your question, Sorry.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify. Basically, we have a custom action that *is* respecting permissions. I just mention that in case it matters. The "Change New Button Order" is not a custom action - it's something SharePoint adds. The problem is that it shows for any viewer of the list, but should only show to people with Manage List permissions.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, AFAIK, you still need another custom action that will override the "Change New Button Order" based on permission that you will set. You need to look at CMDUI.xml, get the target location of "Change New Button Order".