# how to prevent user to change the order of content type

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type

I have 5 folders in a library and each folder is tie a specific content type. I have noticed that users with contribute access can change the content type of the folder by clicking "change new order button" from the folder ... menu. for example, if "folder 1" is tie to "data management" content type and user click the "change new order button" and change it another content type. How can I prevent that?

[image]

Comment: there is this solution but it wont work b/c i have 200+ folders. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39877/library-ecb-shows-change-new-button-order-for-all-users

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, there may not be an out-of-box option to restrict users from using this option. I tried with several custom permission level options and not working.

Comment: thanks for verifying.